# Using Multiple AR Image Anchors to display dynamic 3D Overlay

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, image-recognition, arimageanchor

I'm working on a project wherein we have to detect a certain number of custom QR codes (as ARImageAnchors) and then using the position of these anchors to dynamically display a 3D overlay. To be exact, we are planning to dynamically display a 3D model of human anatomy over the anchors which will be placed on a mannequin. For example, the mannequin we are placing the QR codes on is smaller or bigger than the default size of the 3D model, we would like it to adapt based on the distances between the images.  Below is the sample code I'm thinking of working off from (source: https://www.appcoda.com/arkit-image-recognition/).

```
import UIKit
import ARKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var sceneView: ARSCNView!
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

let fadeDuration: TimeInterval = 0.3
let rotateDuration: TimeInterval = 3
let waitDuration: TimeInterval = 0.5

lazy var fadeAndSpinAction: SCNAction = {
    return .sequence([
        .fadeIn(duration: fadeDuration),
        .rotateBy(x: 0, y: 0, z: CGFloat.pi * 360 / 180, duration: rotateDuration),
        .wait(duration: waitDuration),
        .fadeOut(duration: fadeDuration)
        ])
}()

lazy var fadeAction: SCNAction = {
    return .sequence([
        .fadeOpacity(by: 0.8, duration: fadeDuration),
        .wait(duration: waitDuration),
        .fadeOut(duration: fadeDuration)
        ])
}()

lazy var treeNode: SCNNode = {
    guard let scene = SCNScene(named: "tree.scn"),
        let node = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "tree", recursively: false) else { return SCNNode() }
    let scaleFactor = 0.005
    node.scale = SCNVector3(scaleFactor, scaleFactor, scaleFactor)
    node.eulerAngles.x = -.pi / 2
    return node
}()

lazy var bookNode: SCNNode = {
    guard let scene = SCNScene(named: "book.scn"),
        let node = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "book", recursively: false) else { return SCNNode() }
    let scaleFactor  = 0.1
    node.scale = SCNVector3(scaleFactor, scaleFactor, scaleFactor)
    return node
}()

lazy var mountainNode: SCNNode = {
    guard let scene = SCNScene(named: "mountain.scn"),
        let node = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "mountain", recursively: false) else { return SCNNode() }
    let scaleFactor  = 0.25
    node.scale = SCNVector3(scaleFactor, scaleFactor, scaleFactor)
    node.eulerAngles.x += -.pi / 2
    return node
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    sceneView.delegate = self
    configureLighting()
}

func configureLighting() {
    sceneView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true
    sceneView.automaticallyUpdatesLighting = true
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    resetTrackingConfiguration()
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    sceneView.session.pause()
}

@IBAction func resetButtonDidTouch(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    resetTrackingConfiguration()
}

func resetTrackingConfiguration() {
    guard let referenceImages = ARReferenceImage.referenceImages(inGroupNamed: "AR Resources", bundle: nil) else { return }
    let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
    configuration.detectionImages = referenceImages
    let options: ARSession.RunOptions = [.resetTracking, .removeExistingAnchors]
    sceneView.session.run(configuration, options: options)
    label.text = "Move camera around to detect images"
}
}

extension ViewController: ARSCNViewDelegate {

func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        guard let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor,
            let imageName = imageAnchor.referenceImage.name else { return }

        // TODO: Comment out code
        //            let planeNode = self.getPlaneNode(withReferenceImage: imageAnchor.referenceImage)
        //            planeNode.opacity = 0.0
        //            planeNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi / 2
        //            planeNode.runAction(self.fadeAction)
        //            node.addChildNode(planeNode)

        // TODO: Overlay 3D Object
        let overlayNode = self.getNode(withImageName: imageName)
        overlayNode.opacity = 0
        overlayNode.position.y = 0.2
        overlayNode.runAction(self.fadeAndSpinAction)
        node.addChildNode(overlayNode)

        self.label.text = "Image detected: \"\(imageName)\""
    }
}

func getPlaneNode(withReferenceImage image: ARReferenceImage) -> SCNNode {
    let plane = SCNPlane(width: image.physicalSize.width,
                         height: image.physicalSize.height)
    let node = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
    return node
}

func getNode(withImageName name: String) -> SCNNode {
    var node = SCNNode()
    switch name {
    case "Book":
        node = bookNode
    case "Snow Mountain":
        node = mountainNode
    case "Trees In the Dark":
        node = treeNode
    default:
        break
    }
    return node
}

}
```

I know that the 3D overlay is displayed in the ***renderer*** function above, but it is only displaying on top of a single detected image anchor. Now my question is, **is it possible to reference multiple ARImage anchors to dynamically display a *single* 3D model?**

Being a novice in ARKit and Swift in general, I'm not sure how to go about this problem *yet*. I'm hoping someone might have an idea of how to work around this and point me to the right direction. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As an example then do you mean like placing a model between two image anchors?

Comment: Or are you saying you want to scale your model to fit a patrticular imageAnchor? Will you only be displaying your model once. I think you might need to be a bit more specific :)

Comment: @JoshRobbins Hello Josh, I would like to scale the 3D model to fit multiple image anchors. For example, I'm placing an image anchor on each shoulder of the mannequin and another one on the forehead of the mannequin. Once ARKit detects these images, it will automatically scale it so the **single** 3D overlay will match the size of the mannequin. Does that make sense? The model will only be displayed once.  Once this is done, we are planning to share the AR Scene to other devices to have a "classroom"-like interaction.

Comment: You should likely use an `ARObjectAnchor` and object detection which will be available in iOS 12. `ARImageAnchor`s are more for 2D, high-contrast images, while `ARObjectAnchor` is for detecting 3D objects. It might be possible to detect three qr codes simultaneously using image detection it will involve a lot of work to position a model correctly in response to that. Not to mention a kind of weird user experience.

Comment: Hello @beyowulf, I appreciate your response! I am using ARKit 2.0 using iOS 12 beta and I think it is possible. However, it is only 1 of the issues I'm having right now. I'm more focused on how to utilize multiple anchors to dynamically scale and position a single 3D overlay so it'll look like the human anatomy 3D model will adapt to the mannequin bust where the QR codes are attached. Perhaps you have an idea how to do this?